# How to check whether a the whole column in a pyspark contains a value using Expr

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In pyspark how can i use expr to check whether a whole column contains the value in columnA of that row.

pseudo code below

`df=df.withColumn("Result",  expr(if any the rows in column1 contains the value colA (for this row) then 1 else 0))`

Answer (score 0):

Take an arbitrary example:

```
valuesCol = [('rose','rose is red'),('jasmine','I never saw Jasmine'),('lily','Lili dont be silly'),('daffodil','what a flower')]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(valuesCol,['columnA','columnB'])
df.show()
+--------+-------------------+
| columnA|            columnB|
+--------+-------------------+
|    rose|        rose is red|
| jasmine|I never saw Jasmine|
|    lily| Lili dont be silly|
|daffodil|      what a flower|
+--------+-------------------+
```

Application of `expr()` here. How one can use `expr()`, just look for the corresponding SQL syntax and it should work with `expr()` mostly.

```
df = df.withColumn('columnA_exists',expr("(case when instr(lower(columnB), lower(columnA))>=1 then 1 else 0 end)"))
df.show()
+--------+-------------------+--------------+
| columnA|            columnB|columnA_exists|
+--------+-------------------+--------------+
|    rose|        rose is red|             1|
| jasmine|I never saw Jasmine|             1|
|    lily| Lili dont be silly|             0|
|daffodil|      what a flower|             0|
+--------+-------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: so with the 1st line, rose is red would be on another row

Maybe its not possible in spark